# How to default open a + button in Weebly

Tags: html, css, weebly

I'm trying to default a Description + button to open so my customers don't have to click the + to open the button to view the description, i'd like it to default open and be able to be closed.  Here is the current code and i've been unable to manipulate it to default open.

/* Short Description */

```
#wsite-com-product-short-description {
margin: 30px auto 0;
padding-top: 30px;
border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
max-height: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: max-height .65s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: max-height .65s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: max-height .65s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: max-height .65s ease-in-out;
transition: max-height .65s ease-in-out;
}

#wsite-com-product-short-description:before {
content: 'DESCRIPTION +';
display: block;
font-family: "Montserrat";
font-size: .85em;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#wsite-com-product-short-description.open {
max-height: 800px;
}

#wsite-com-product-short-description.open:before {
content: 'DESCRIPTION -';
}
```

Comment: Can you provide link to the site?

Comment: Sure thing, the link is: http://www.simplysheetsmonograms.com/store/p2/Mint_Chevron_Cosmetic_Bag.html

Answer (score 0):

Include the followin in your custom CSS.

```
#wsite-com-product-short-description {
    max-height: 800px !important;
}
```

It forces the description to be expanded by setting it's minimum height.